# CakePHP URL convert prefix to a parameter

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.0, prefix

I have a project where every thing is related to the table named `Apps`.

Let's say that my CakePHP root accessed by `http://my-domain/`

I want to design my URLs to be as the following:

```
http://my-domain/:app-name/:plugin/:controller/:action/.....
```

In other words I want to prefix my URLs with the **app-name** which will be reflected to something like:

```
http://my-domain/Plgn/Cntl/Action/..... ?app-name={app-name}
```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing ?

Comment: thanks @ndm but I dont want to create folders for each App, I want the same project files to treat the url after parsing the prefix, in fact I may need something like the prefix but not the prefix itself